# IIS 8.0 default Page not Loading

Tags: html, iis-8

I have default regular html page (testing purposes) when I try to browse that page from IIS, it keeps loading, It's like he doesn't know where the Page is ...

I have a SQL Server 2012 with IIS 8.0
My Default Web Site Config :
**Binding**

1. Type : http
2. Port : 80
3. IP Adrs : Domain IP

Since the page is on the server I do not specify the host Name (not sure if that's the issue)

**Basic Settings**

1. Pool : .NET v4.5
2. Physical path : C:\inetpub\wwwroot

In the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder I have a index.html file which is just a test I was running to test IIS

html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
```

My Issue is that when I open Default Web Site and I try to Browse it, It keeps loading and never retrieves the file ... How can I fix this and/or how can I debug this ?

EDIT : 
My main issues is that my WCF C# Service doesn't work but then I tried to simply call that html file that I create and then I understood that it has something to do with IIS itself or I really messed up something there, also if you wish to know how I was doing my steps for my WCF C# Service here's the video

Video :
[enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBAs3zw6rq0)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Man, after reassearching a lot, I've found out that you need to give access on the IIS_USERS to you're application rather than the web.config file